# Can max_size() be undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, containers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c++23

In the C++ standard, `max_size()` is defined as

> *Returns*: `distance(begin(), end())` for the largest possible container.

- [[container.reqmts] `max_size`](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.reqmts#lib:max_size,containers)

Initially, this looks good, and there is no *Preconditions* paragraph. However, `std::distance` returns `(last - first)` ([[iterator.operations] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.operations#5)) and this is possibly undefined behavior for random access iterators (note the *Preconditions* in [[iterator.requirements] `b - a`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#tab:randomaccessiterator-row-7)).

What is the standard actually trying to say here?

1. `max_size()` has no preconditions, so while it isn't *explicitly* stated, the largest possible container is required to have a `max_size()` so that `distance(begin(), end())` is well-defined.
2. `max_size()` is missing a *Preconditions* paragraph, and it's possible for `max_size()` to be undefined behavior if `end() - begin()` and by proxy, `std::distance(begin(), end())` is UB.
3. Something else.

The underlying question is:

> Does the absence of a *Preconditions* paragraph impose requirements on the implementation, or is it an editorial mistake?

There might not be a clear answer to this. `std::distance` is defined in terms of `(last - first)`, which can be undefined behavior, but `std::distance` also doesn't have a precondition which requires that the iterator difference is representable. It's not plausible that `&b - &a` is UB but `std::distance(&a, &b)` is well-defined.

Based on this, I think it's an editorial mistake, `max_size()` is missing a precondition, and can be undefined. However, I may be missing something here.

Comment: Only (1) would make sense to me.

Comment: It could be UB because `end()` is one beyond the end of the size of the container and max_size() would be equal to the maximum addressable size of a container. So it is up to max_size to return a size at least one less than the maximum addressble size.

Comment: `max_size()` takes no arguments and returns a constant that doesn't depend on the current state of a container. What kind of preconditions might that function have have?

Comment: In my interpretation, `max_size()` is the theoretical maximum size based on how the vector was implemented.  that means the defined behavior is already baked into the value.

Comment: @Evg Something like "*Preconditions:* `distance(begin(), end())` is well-defined for the largest possible container.". In other words, forwarding the preconditions that `std::distance` has or should have.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- agreed, with emphasis on the "theoretical";  it doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: I guess the intention of the standard is to say that `distance(begin(), end())` is always well-defined unless iterators point into different containers. Otherwise, `size()`, which returns `distance(begin(), end())`, would have similar preconditions and this makes no sense.

Comment: Is it possible for a well-formed expression to have undefined behavior? (I would think not, but what do the precise technical definitions say?) The expression `c.max_size()` is required to be "[well-formed and have the specified semantics](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.reqmts#1)".

Comment: @JaMiT yes. The expression `0 / 0` is well-formed but has undefined behavior if evaluated. Well/Ill-formedness refers to whether the code is "valid C++" so to speak.